# ac outlet 2white 2 black 2red. ceiling light stays on

Tags: electrical, wiring

I had no power in the bathrooms and bedrooms. I found a outlet in the master bedroom with poor connections. Replaced the outlet. Whites on silver side, blacks on brass. Tab not broken. And two reds on each black wires. When i put it all together the bedroom ceiling light came on but  the switch on the wall did not control it. switch has a black and white (no reds). two switches one for ceiling light and fan. This is not my house. Dont know the history. I am not an electrician but understand the basics. I have power in the bathrooms now.
I want to think that those red wires have something to do with the ceiling light power bypassing the switch on the wall. Just not sure. I wonder if someone else did some work before me?

Comment: The bedroom shall not have anything to do with bathroom

Comment: @Traveler Only in the last couple decades. Before that it could.

Comment: If it's not your house, you shouldn't be doing electrical work in it. You can guide & supervise the homeowner if you're not an electrician but you can't do all the work. If it's a rental, you _certainly_ shouldn't be doing the work - call the landlord and he'll call out an electrician.